# How to use STAR detector in openCV 3 with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to use the STAR detector in openCV 3, and it's throwing an error:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('grand_central_terminal.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

star = cv2.xfeatures2d.StarDetector_create()
(kps, descs) = star.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
print("# of keypoints: {}".format(len(kps))) # should be 459
```

The error it gives is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quiz.py", line 8, in <module>
    (kps, descs) = star.detectAndCompute(gray, None)
cv2.error: /home/travis/miniconda/conda-bld/work/opencv-3.1.0/modules/features2d/src/feature2d.cpp:144: error: (-213)  in function detectAndCompute
```

Here's the image:
[image: grand_central_terminal.png]

Running on ubuntu 16.04LTS 64-bit with python 3.5 and anaconda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error code `-213` you are receiving indicates that the `detectAndCompute` method is not implemented for the STAR detector. That is because STAR is only a feature detector, not a combination detector and descriptor. Your code can be fixed by calling the `detect` method instead:

```
kps = star.detect(gray)
```

Comment: I see, so how is the star.detectAndCompute supposed to work?

Comment: `star.detectAndCompute` isn't supposed to work. It seems like an unfortunate accident the method exists at all. Some things in the `xfeatures2d` module are both detectors and descriptors (like ORB or SIFT), and those make use of `detectAndCompute`. STAR is only a feature detector, but will not compute descriptors for those keypoints.